# Java server code passes data to running java program

Tags: java, lego-mindstorms, lejos-nxj

Is there a way I can pass data, from Java server code, to a Java program which is already running?

I need to transfer data in real time, and I cannot integrate the two programs as they use a different compiler.

Any ideas?
Thanks

** ADDED INFO **

I am looking to control a robot over the internet. I have the server code which communicates with the client, and a program coded in a unique type of Java code (LeJOS if anyone is familiar with it). From the server side I need to pass data to the PC LeJOS Program in real time. Hence, the LeJOS PC program must be able to receive some data from the server code, whilst it is running.

Is this possible? To clarify, both the server code and the LeJOS PC Program will be running on the same machine.

Another possibility could be to integrate the server code and LeJOS PC program into one, so that the LeJOS PC program is run directly from the server code. Would it be possible to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: A socket? A service (on either side, I suppose)?

Comment: The program runs on the server itself.

Comment: What do you mean, "the program runs on the server itself"? Depending on which brick you have, you're going to use either the existing BT or USB comms provided in the related API. There are tutorials for both on the LeJOS site. That kind of information is important to provide up-front as it changes the nature of the answer quite a bit.

Comment: For the robot, I have a program which runs on a PC (my server) and another which runs on the robot. This part is fine as LeJOS provide good sample programs.

The problem I have is getting a command (such as "move left") from the server, to the robot PC program whilst the PC program is running. 

The PC robot program runs on the server itself.

Comment: Right, I'm saying the comms tutorials on the lejos site should take care of that issue.

Comment: Doesnt the comms tutorial deal with connections between the PC and the NXT? I am talking about sending and instruction from my server code to  the LeJOS PC program.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. The PC side can be compiled with regular Java; why do you want *two* programs running on the PC? Just have one that talks to the bot. If you're dead-set on having two, then normal Java communications stuff (sockets, services, etc.) applies as it did originally.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, that's a pretty broad question, and it really depends on what the restrictions are on your app. Basically you're doing to have to transfer it through some intermediary channel.

Options:

- Have the server write the data to a file, and have the Java app read it
- Have the Java app connect to the server via a Socket and read the data

...and going to much  more complicated methods:

- [RMI (Remote Method Invocation)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html)

If you need a more specific answer, you'll have to tell us more about:

- why are you transferring this data?
- what sort of data you're trying to transfer between the two apps?
- do you have access to modify the two programs, or is their code not controlled by you?
- what have you already tried?

Comment: I am looking to control a robot over the internet. I have the server code which communicates with the client, and a program coded in a unique type of Java code (LeJOS if anyone is familiar with it).

From the server code I need to pass data to the robot program which specifies how the robot should move. I will be looking to pass a stream of data in both directions. The data is an instruction (ie move left, right etc).

I have access to both programs. Unfortunately I am not familiar with Java so I do not know if this is possible!

Comment: Ok, well put all of that in the original question. We're programmers here - we love details, so don't hold back with the important details, and you're encouraged to post actual code whenever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Have the client connect to the server via a socket. It doesn't matter if they're both running on the same machine or not. That is pretty much they way you do 'ipc' in Java, and if you want to extend the control over the network you'll have to go there anyway.

You can send data bidirectionally, so its up to you how you want to use that. The simplest way to implement your protocol is something textual, that way its easy to debug. If you can make it request/response oriented then that makes things simpler too.

Here's a basic tutorial for network IO in Java. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

Good luck.